# DX9 style intristics are disabled when not in dx9 compatibility mode?

Tags: directx-11, hlsl

I am currently writing an `HLSL` shader for a basic Gaussian blur. The shader code is straight forward, but I keep getting an error:

> DX9 style intristics are disabled when not in dx9 compatibility mode. (LN#: 19)

This tells me that line 19 in my code is the issue, and I believe it is either due to `tex2D` or `Sampler` in that particular line.

```
#include "Common.hlsl"

Texture2D Texture0 : register(t0);
SamplerState Sampler : register(s0);

float4 PSMain(PixelShaderInput pixel) : SV_Target {
    float2 uv = pixel.TextureUV; // This is TEXCOORD0.
    float4 result = 0.0f;

    float offsets[21] = { ... };
    float weights[21] = { ... };

    // Blur horizontally.
    for (int x = 0; x < 21; x++)
        result += tex2D(Sampler, float2(uv.x + offsets[x], uv.y)) * weights[x];

    return result;
}
```

See below for notes about the code, and my questions.

---

### Notes

I have to hand type my code into StackOverflow due to my code being on a computer without a connection. Therefore:

- Any spelling or case errors present here do not exist in code.
- The absence of values inside of `offsets` and `weights` is intentional.

  - This is because there are 21 values in each and I didn't feel like typing them all.
  - `offsets` is every integer from `-10` to `10`.
  - `weights` ranges from `0.01` to `0.25` and back to `0.01`.
- The line count here is smaller due to the absence mentioned prior.

  - The line number of the error here is `15`.
  - The column range is `13 - 59` which encapsulates `tex2D` and `Sampler`.

---

### My Questions

- Am I using the wrong data type for `Sampler` in the `tex2D` call?
- Is `tex2D` deprecated in `DirectX 11`?
- What should I be using instead?
- What am I doing wrong here as that is my only error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some extensive searching, I've found out that `tex2D` is no longer supported from `ps_4_0` and up. Well, `4_0` will work in legacy mode, but it doesn't work it `5_0` which is what I am using.

> Shader Model : Supported
>
> Shader Model 4 : yes (pixel shader only), but you must use the legacy compile option when compiling.
>   Shader Model 3 (DirectX HLSL) : yes (pixel shader only)
>   Shader Model 2 (DirectX HLSL) : yes (pixel shader only)
>   Shader Model 1 (DirectX HLSL) : yes (pixel shader only)

This has been replaced by `Texture2D`; the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-to-sample) is available for it. Below is an example from the mentioned documentation:

```
// Object Declarations
Texture2D g_MeshTexture;    
SamplerState MeshTextureSampler
{
    Filter = MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
    AddressU = Wrap;
    AddressV = Wrap;
};

struct VS_OUTPUT
{
    float4 Position   : SV_POSITION; 
    float4 Diffuse    : COLOR0;
    float2 TextureUV  : TEXCOORD0; 
};

VS_OUTPUT In;

// Shader body calling the intrinsic function
Output.RGBColor = g_MeshTexture.Sample(MeshTextureSampler, In.TextureUV) * In.Diffuse;
```

To replace the `tex2D` call in my code:

```
result += Texture0.Sample(Sampler, float2(uv.x + offsets[x], uv.y)) * weights[x];
```

Also, note that the code in this post is for the horizontal pass of a Gaussian blur.

Comment: You should use the modern syntax if possible. That said, you can just use ``/Gec`` switch or the ``D3DCOMPILE_ENABLE_BACKWARDS_COMPATIBILITY`` flag to support the older intrinsics--you also can't use ``Ges`` / ``D3DCOMPILE_ENABLE_STRICTNESS`` if you enable the older syntax. I'd love to say the Microsoft docs are 100% accurate, but they are not so the lack of an explicit mention of Shader Model 5 or even Shader Model 6 doesn't mean anything specific.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Thanks for pointing that out; I actually checked the documentation prior to using the call, but couldn't figure out the backwards compatibility issue. I completely agree that they aren't 100% accurate.