# Replacing PixelShaderCompile task with fxc.exe (necessitated by moving to VS2022). Getting same functionality. Putting in resource (embedded?)

Tags: directx, hlsl, fragment-shader, msbuild-task

As some may know, support for  PixelShaderCompile has been done away with as of VS2022. One is suppose to use fxc.exe (I believe).  For a discussion of this, see:

[Build pixel shader project in VS2022](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73657761/build-pixel-shader-project-in-vs2022/74826512?noredirect=1#comment133824757_74826512)

I inherited a LARGE project I need to build.  I'm not familiar with the DirectX parts of it, and I don't think I need to be right away. However, I do need to build and run it.
The build line for the shader stuff was:

```
 <Target Name="EffectCompile" Condition="'@(Effect)' != '' ">
    <PixelShaderCompile Sources="@(Effect)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Outputs" ItemName="Resource" />
    </PixelShaderCompile>
  </Target>
```

Based on the article above (mostly from https://stackoverflow.com/users/403671/simon-mourier) I tried the following code:

```
<Target Name="EffectCompile" Condition="'@(Effect)' != '' ">
  <Exec Command="&quot;$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x64\fxc.exe&quot; /T ps_3_0 /Fo %(Effect.Identity).ps %(Effect.Identity)"/>
</Target>
```

which compiles fine and produces .ps files.  However, I believe the first code block is somehow embedding said .ps files in a "resource" or something?  To be honest, I'm not familiar with the syntax of either command and am having trouble finding documentation and/or examples.  I'm guessing this is something DirectX gurus do all the time?

Any ideas how to get started or research some more?

Dave

UPDATE.  Thanks once again to Simon Mourier (see below) and [Build pixel shader project in VS2022](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73657761/build-pixel-shader-project-in-vs2022/74826512?noredirect=1#comment133824757_74826512)

In case anyone wants to see a full project file for reference, here is one (below).  Most relevant stuff is towards the bottom.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
 
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>9.0.30729</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{4EB52AEE-95E0-42AC-89F5-251B832CF7CE}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>Cyntellect.ShaderEffects</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>ShaderEffects</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <FileUpgradeFlags>
    </FileUpgradeFlags>
    <OldToolsVersion>3.5</OldToolsVersion>
    <UpgradeBackupLocation />
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x64'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>..\..\bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <DocumentationFile>..\..\doc\ShaderEffects.xml</DocumentationFile>
    <NoWarn>1607</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>AllRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64'">
    <OutputPath>..\..\bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <DocumentationFile>..\..\doc\ShaderEffects.xml</DocumentationFile>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>AllRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Test|x64'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>..\..\bin\Test\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <DocumentationFile>..\..\doc\ShaderEffects.xml</DocumentationFile>
    <NoWarn>1607</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>AllRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core">
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="WindowsBase">
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="PresentationCore">
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="PresentationFramework">
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="..\..\VersionAssemblyInfo.cs">
      <Link>Properties\VersionAssemblyInfo.cs</Link>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="..\CPAssemblyInfo.cs">
      <Link>Properties\CPAssemblyInfo.cs</Link>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="EffectFiles\BandedSwirlEffect.cs" />
    <Compile Include="EffectFiles\BloomEffect.cs" />
    <Compile Include="EffectFiles\BrightExtractEffect.cs" />
    <Compile Include="EffectFiles\ColorKeyAlphaEffect.cs" />
    <Compile Include="EffectFiles\ColorToneEffect.cs" />
    <Compile Include="EffectFiles\CompensationEffect.cs" />
    <Compile Include="EffectFiles\CompensationEffect2Channels.cs" />
    <Compile Include="EffectFiles\CompensationEffect3Channels.cs" />
    <Compile Include="EffectFiles\CompensationEffect5Channels.cs" />
    <Compile Include="EffectFiles\CompensationEffect4Channels.cs" />
    <Compile Include="EffectFiles\ContrastAdjustEffect.cs" />
    <Compile Include="EffectFiles\DirectionalBlurEffect.cs" />
    <Compile Include="EffectFiles\EmbossedEffect.cs" />
    <Compile Include="EffectFiles\GloomEffect.cs" />
    <Compile Include="EffectFiles\GrowablePoissonDiskEffect.cs" />
    <Compile Include="EffectFiles\InvertColorEffect.cs" />
    <Compile Include="EffectFiles\LightStreakEffect.cs" />
    <Compile Include="EffectFiles\MagnifyEffect.cs" />
    <Compile Include="EffectFiles\MonochromeEffect.cs" />
    <Compile Include="EffectFiles\PinchEffect.cs" />
    <Compile Include="EffectFiles\PixelateEffect.cs" />
    <Compile Include="EffectFiles\RippleEffect.cs" />
    <Compile Include="EffectFiles\SharpenEffect.cs" />
    <Compile Include="EffectFiles\SmoothMagnifyEffect.cs" />
    <Compile Include="EffectFiles\SwirlEffect.cs" />
    <Compile Include="EffectFiles\ToneMappingEffect.cs" />
    <Compile Include="EffectFiles\ToonShaderEffect.cs" />
    <Compile Include="EffectFiles\ZoomBlurEffect.cs" />
    <Compile Include="EffectLibrary.cs">
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Service Include="{94E38DFF-614B-4cbd-B67C-F211BB35CE8B}" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Effect Include="ShaderSource\BandedSwirl.fx" />
    <Effect Include="ShaderSource\Bloom.fx" />
    <Effect Include="ShaderSource\BrightExtract.fx" />
    <Effect Include="ShaderSource\ColorKeyAlpha.fx" />
    <Effect Include="ShaderSource\ColorTone.fx" />
    <Effect Include="ShaderSource\Compensation.fx" />
    <Effect Include="ShaderSource\Compensation2Channels.fx" />
    <Effect Include="ShaderSource\Compensation3Channels.fx" />
    <Effect Include="ShaderSource\Compensation4Channels.fx" />
    <Effect Include="ShaderSource\ContrastAdjust.fx" />
    <Effect Include="ShaderSource\DirectionalBlur.fx" />
    <Effect Include="ShaderSource\Embossed.fx" />
    <Effect Include="ShaderSource\Gloom.fx" />
    <Effect Include="ShaderSource\GrowablePoissonDisk.fx" />
    <Effect Include="ShaderSource\InvertColor.fx" />
    <Effect Include="ShaderSource\LightStreak.fx" />
    <Effect Include="ShaderSource\Magnify.fx" />
    <Effect Include="ShaderSource\Monochrome.fx" />
    <Effect Include="ShaderSource\Pinch.fx" />
    <Effect Include="ShaderSource\Pixelate.fx" />
    <Effect Include="ShaderSource\Ripple.fx" />
    <Effect Include="ShaderSource\Sharpen.fx" />
    <Effect Include="ShaderSource\SmoothMagnify.fx" />
    <Effect Include="ShaderSource\Swirl.fx" />
    <Effect Include="ShaderSource\ToneMapping.fx" />
    <Effect Include="ShaderSource\ToonShader.fx" />
    <Effect Include="ShaderSource\WaveEffect.fx" />
    <Effect Include="ShaderSource\ZoomBlur.fx" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Effect Include="ShaderSource\Compensation5Channels.fx" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  
 <Target Name="EffectCompile" Condition="'@(Effect)' != '' ">
  <Exec Command="&quot;$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x64\fxc.exe&quot; /T ps_3_0 /Fo %(Effect.RelativeDir)%(Effect.FileName).ps %(Effect.Identity)"/>
  <!-- Add this if you need to embed the file as WPF resources -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="%(Effect.RelativeDir)%(Effect.FileName).ps" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Add effect compilation to the PrepareResourcesDependsOn so that the effect fx  get compiled before resources are collected -->
    <PrepareResourcesDependsOn>EffectCompile;$(PrepareResourcesDependsOn)</PrepareResourcesDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PreBuildEvent>
    </PreBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: What version of the DirectX API is the project using, i.e. is it DX9, 10, 11 or 12 (or earlier than DX9???) Modern shader source code (which should have a `.hlsl` file extension) is usually compiled by FXC (or DXC for SM 6 and above) into a _compiled shader object_ file (having a `.cso` extension).

Comment: The problem is "only" an msbuild problem. I've fixed my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74826512/403671 to generate ps file with same path & name (.ps instead of .fx) and embed them as resources at the same time.

Comment: @SimonMourier  Thanks once again!  Can you write a brief answer so I can accept and give you much deserved credit?  I modified my question to give an update with the complete project file.   Notice the PrepareResourcesDependsOn torwards the bottom. I'm not sure if this is needed or not. I didn't see it in your answer.  I'd humbly suggest that in your answer you put any references to source material/tutorials/examples/etc.  Find info on this subject seems tough!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original [PixelShaderCompile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74826512/403671) task was declared like this in a .csproj:

```
<Target Name="EffectCompile" Condition="'@(Effect)' != '' ">
  <PixelShaderCompile Sources="@(Effect)">
    <Output TaskParameter="Outputs" ItemName="Resource" />
  </PixelShaderCompile>
</Target>
```

What this did is 1) compile the .fx files as .ps files (compiled effects) and 2) declare them as `Resource` for the **MSBuild** system (same as Visual Studio Build Action `Resource`) which is understood by WPF project types as WPF resources:

[image]

So, when you're building for WPF, you want to emulate that behavior, which you can do like this (my [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74826512/403671) initially only had the `Exec` command):

```
<Target Name="EffectCompile" Condition="'@(Effect)' != '' ">
  <Exec Command="&quot;$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x64\fxc.exe&quot; /T ps_3_0 /Fo %(Effect.RelativeDir)%(Effect.FileName).ps %(Effect.Identity)"/>

  <!-- Add this if you need to embed the file as WPF resources -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="%(Effect.RelativeDir)%(Effect.FileName).ps" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! A very useful answer.

Comment: Simon I don't know if you'll see this, but I notice things are not working on another machine.  That is, I made the changes discussed and it runs on my development machine fine.  On a lab machine, the shading is not showing up. No error, just no shading. I can't see the problem with Dependencies or asmspy. However, I note that for development  Windows SDK  was needed.  Is there something from Windows SDK that is needed on the target machine? Presumably one should not put SDK on a target machine. This is just now coming up as our QA department is a little behind :)

Comment: @dave - it's perfectly possible that something fails at runtime, but it's a deployment issue (software dependencies, drivers, directx support level, hardware, etc.), it's unrelated to the compilation steps, ie: the binaries produced by this csproj should be exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks, those were my thoughts as well. I just need to track down the missing dependency (easier said than done :) ).  I should have mentioned that the old code with PixelShaderCompile  works fine on the other machines.  I'm guessing there is some runtime requirement when using Windows SDK version 10.  The lab machine in question even has Visual Studio 2022 installed so it's not a dependency that Visual Studio 2022 introduced!  Tricky stuff!

Comment: I'm wondering if it is as simple as the  ps_3_0 in the fxc command. My limited understanding is that this is a shader mode and could be 2 to 5 (version 1 not supported with fxc.  Do you know if the old command "PixelShaderCompile " used shader models, and if so which version? It's possible that the computers that are giving me grief don't support ps_3_0. I'm not sure how to determine this.

Comment: @dave - I don't have the old binaries at hand but it's possible it used ps_2_0 you can try that (obviously the shader code must not use newer than ps_2_0 instructions or it won't compile). If a machine doesn't support ps_3_0 it means it has 20+ years software/hardware: DirectX9 with XP (2002). ps_3_0 is DirectX9.0C with Vista (2006). Use DxDiag (feature levels) to check that, here is information for DirectX11 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/overviews-direct3d-11-devices-downlevel-intro I have no idea how DxDiag looks like on old PCs

Comment: Once again, THANKS!  The changing to 2_0 got it working on the lab machine.  Still a mystery.  The lab computer has a fairly new NVIDIA T1000 card.  And as I said, 3_0 worked on my computer (NVIDIA RTX A2000). The code itself is old, and attempts to use 4_0 and 5_0 got "DX9 style intristics are disabled when not in dx9 compatibility mode." during compile.  This posting indicates that thing may get weird when using older code:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53283724/dx9-style-intristics-are-disabled-when-not-in-dx9-compatibility-mode  Hope this helps others!